# Should [tag:stack] be split?

Tags: discussion, tags

While there are only 8 questions tagged with [stack](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack), it *might* make sense to separate *protocol stack* questions from *activation record stack* (or more generally stack as as software data structure) and from evaluation stack (which could use a tag text like 'stack-processor' even though it would apply to the Java VM and probably to x87).

So would it be appropriate to retag the protocol stack questions with a new tag [protocol-stack](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protocol-stack) and use [stack](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack) for the software data structure (including activation record stack) perhaps with a note in the info text/tag wiki summary that questions about evaluation stacks (if any are ever asked) would be tagged [stack-processor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-processor)?

In hindsight, perhaps protocol stack questions might be moved to [protocol](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protocol).

Answer (score 5):

Frankly, it sounds like the tag should just be scrubbed. 8 questions and 3 different meanings? The tag is meaningless.

Heck, protocol is a generic tag itself.

Comment: Actually, there were not any questions for the third (execution stack) meaning. I suspect you are correct since in neither case would the tag communicate much interesting/useful information (it is not a subject anyone is likely to follow or use for a tag [rather than Q/A text] search).